# Reordering repeated columns according to the specific order using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has columns and rows with repeated index names with ordered suscripts. I want to reorder them such that they will follow a specific order that I assign. I made a simple example manually as below. This code will produce *df*, which is dataframe that has repeated columns and rows. I want to use the column vector *order* so that my new dataframe *df_new* will have columns and rows that will follow the order assigned by *order* (while the suscript numbers are in increasing order).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [11, 3, 10, 9, 6, 9],
                   1: [12, 4, 11, 8, 5, 8],
                   2: [13, 5, 12, 7, 4, 7],
                   3: [14, 6, 13, 6, 3, 6],
                   4: [15, 7, 14, 5, 2, 5],
                   5: [16, 8, 15, 4, 1, 4]})
df = df.rename({0:"apple1", 1:"apple2",2:"banana1",3:"banana2",4:"pear1",5:"pear2"}, axis='columns')
df = df.rename({0:"apple1", 1:"apple2",2:"banana1",3:"banana2",4:"pear1",5:"pear2"}, axis='index')

order = ["banana", "pear", "apple" ]

df_new = pd.DataFrame({2: [12, 7, 4, 7, 13, 5],
                       3: [13, 6, 3, 6, 14, 6],
                       4: [14, 5, 2, 5, 15, 7],
                       5: [15, 4, 1, 4, 16, 8],
                       0: [10, 9, 6, 9, 11, 3],
                       1: [11, 8, 5, 8, 12, 4]})
df_new = df_new.rename({0:"apple1", 1:"apple2",2:"banana1",3:"banana2",4:"pear1",5:"pear2"}, axis='columns')
df_new = df_new.rename({0:"apple1", 1:"apple2",2:"banana1",3:"banana2",4:"pear1",5:"pear2"}, axis='index')

df
df_new
```

I posted the desired outcome image (I was not sure how I could put the output of above code in this question) as below. Could anyone please give me a generic way to reorder these repeated columns and rows using a specific order (as well as the corresponding cells? Thank you very much!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be:

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract) to create a multi index with the names:

```
# Extract the Numeric and Alphabetical Parts and convert to MultiIndex
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.columns.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.index.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
)
```

```
0        apple     banana     pear    
1            1   2      1   2    1   2
0      1                              
apple  1    11  12     13  14   15  16
       2     3   4      5   6    7   8
banana 1    10  11     12  13   14  15
       2     9   8      7   6    5   4
pear   1     6   5      4   3    2   1
       2     9   8      7   6    5   4
```

Then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) level=0 on both index and columns with the `order`:

```
order = ["banana", "pear", "apple"]
df = df.reindex(index=order, columns=order, level=0)
```

```
0        banana     pear     apple    
1             1   2    1   2     1   2
0      1                              
banana 1     12  13   14  15    10  11
       2      7   6    5   4     9   8
pear   1      4   3    2   1     6   5
       2      7   6    5   4     9   8
apple  1     13  14   15  16    11  12
       2      5   6    7   8     3   4
```

Then collapse the multi-index with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html#pandas-index-map):

```
df.index = df.index.map(''.join)
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
```

```
         banana1  banana2  pear1  pear2  apple1  apple2
banana1       12       13     14     15      10      11
banana2        7        6      5      4       9       8
pear1          4        3      2      1       6       5
pear2          7        6      5      4       9       8
apple1        13       14     15     16      11      12
apple2         5        6      7      8       3       4
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = ['apple1', 'apple2', 'banana1', 'banana2', 'pear1', 'pear2']
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[11, 3, 10, 9, 6, 9],
     [12, 4, 11, 8, 5, 8],
     [13, 5, 12, 7, 4, 7],
     [14, 6, 13, 6, 3, 6],
     [15, 7, 14, 5, 2, 5],
     [16, 8, 15, 4, 1, 4]],
    index=idx,
    columns=idx
)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.columns.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.index.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
)

order = ["banana", "pear", "apple"]
df = df.reindex(index=order, columns=order, level=0)

df.index = df.index.map(''.join)
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
print(df)
```

---

(Optional) Convert level 1 to int and sort numerically with [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.columns.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.index.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
)
# Convert level 1 to int on both index and columns 
df.index = [df.index.get_level_values(0),
            df.index.get_level_values(1).astype(int)]

df.columns = [df.columns.get_level_values(0),
              df.columns.get_level_values(1).astype(int)]

order = ["banana", "pear", "apple"]
df = (
    df
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=0)  # Sort level 1 on each axis
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
        .reindex(index=order, columns=order, level=0)
)

# Fix map to handle non-numeric types
df.index = df.index.map(lambda s: ''.join(map(str, s)))
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda s: ''.join(map(str, s)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I applied your method to the actual dataset and the rows seems to work well(it got re-ordered as I desired)! However, I got NaN in one of the column label (not the values in that column) and I was wondering what could have caused this problem..!

Comment: The current regex is A-Za-z values followed by numbers. If a label didn't have a numeric value then extract would've given NaN back as having not found that pattern. That pattern is be overly simplistic for all use cases.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I figured out and solved the problem. Also, I wanted to ask a last question: in sort_index, the numbers after the name of fruits are sorted as (1, 11, 12... 19, 2, 21, 22...29). I was wondering if it is possible to sort so that it will be in increasing order (i.e. 1, 2, 3, .... 10, 11, 12, 13, ...). I thought maybe I could re-assign the type of level 1 column and rows as an integer and put ascending=True in sort_index, but I was not sure how I could change the type of level=1 columns and index (also I was not sure if my idea is right).

Comment: Yeah. I actually added that when you asked your last question. Check out the last code block which goes over how to convert level 1 to ints to numerically sort it. =)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!